# Running Python script on windows task scheduler

Tags: python, pycharm, python-idle, windows-task-scheduler

I have a program in my pycharm with all the required packages installed.

I want to run windows task scheduler to run this program.

The problem is when task scheduler runs the program, it doesn't seem to run the script from pycharm but runs it from IDLE (I'm assuming so). the IDLE gives out error for "modules not found".

Can any kind soul please advise:

1. how to configure my pycharm code (with all its installed packages) to be the same in the IDLE; or
2. how to run the task scheduler directly from pycharm instead; or
3. how to install all the packages in IDLE.

Comment: Your task scheduler will not run your file with IDLE unless you explicitly ask it to.  In fact, I do not think it possible to run it through IDLE and exit.  IDLE is for development, not production running.  Packages are installed in python, not IDLE, and the message comes from a particular python.exe, not from IDLE.  You likely have two pythons on your system.  Check Q&As about synchronizing package installs with pip.

Answer (score 0):

The putting the shebang at the start of your script:

```py
#! python3

...
```